# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil for "2015-11-20 13:42:00.000000"

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I know there are many similar questions but I can't figure out my problem.

I want to convert a `String` like `"2015-11-20 13:42:00.000000"` to NSDate.

My code is like below.

```
let date:String
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
if let value = row["date"]?.asString() {
    date = value
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date) // formattedDate is nil
}
```

Comment: [use NSDataDetector when the format is unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071428/how-do-i-resolve-this-build-issue-cannot-assign-to-property-date-is-a-get-o/34072848#34072848)

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your `dateFormat` with following

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
```

As uppercase `S` represents fraction of second.

More detail about DateTime Format table is available [here](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: Thank you Dipen Panchasara. I tried it but same result.

Comment: @tomo if still its not working then there is something wrong with date string you pass to dateFormatter. pass static date like `let fornmattedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-11-20 13:42:00.000000")` and check result, if it returns date there is something wrong with your input. happy coding :)

Comment: One more thing remove if condition if you really don't want to check. instead check for empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Please secure your code by [saving ponies](http://alisoftware.github.io/swift/2015/09/06/thinking-in-swift-1/) !

```
let date = "2015-11-20 13:42:00.000000"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
if let fornmattedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date) as NSDate {
print ("The formated date is \(fornmattedDate)")
} else {
     print ("\(date) is not a valid date")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
    let date = "2015-11-20 13:42:00.000000"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
    let fornmattedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date) as NSDate!
    print ("The formated date is \(fornmattedDate)")
```

**Output:-**
    The formated date is 2015-11-20 21:42:00 +0000