# "xx" is get-only property - How to Assign decoded Json Data to class (nested view model) Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui, computed-properties

I have a watchapp that receives parent view model (nested view model) data from iPhone via json/file transfer. I am using "Communicator" library by @KaneCheshire.

The data flow is

1. Watch App launches - loading empty Parent View Model (`ReceivedDayProgViewModel`) into the app and showing activity indicator in `WatchLoadingView`.
2. `WatchLoadingView` set-up observer to receive actual json data/file from iPhone
3. `WatchLoadingView`'s observer receives actual json data, decodes them into ParentViewModel object (`ReceivedDayProgViewModel`)

After step 3, I am having difficulty actually assigning the decoded object to the initially empty Parent View Model (`ReceivedDayProgViewModel`). There is a error message saying "`**Cannot assign to property: 'receivedDayProgramVM' is a get-only property**`"

So I did look up the error and have an idea that my parent View Model is actually a "computed-property" instead of stored property - [How do I resolve this build issue - cannot assign to property: 'date' is a get only property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071428/how-do-i-resolve-this-build-issue-cannot-assign-to-property-date-is-a-get-o) **But I am still struggling to add codes to ensure "set/write" function is embedded in the Parent View Model(`ReceivedDayProgViewModel`).**

Would appreciate any guidance/advice on how I can change my code to allow "set/write" operation in Parent View Model (`ReceivedDayProgViewModel`) so below step can be fulfilled.

4. Assign decoded object (`let ReceivedDayProgViewModel = try! decoder.decode(ReceivedDayProgViewModel.self, from: ReceivedDayProgVMData)`) (with values/data from iPhone) into the `@StateObject` in `ContentView`  (`receivedDayProgramVM`)

Parent View Model

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ReceivedDayProgViewModel: ObservableObject, Codable {
    
    @Published var workoutModel = WorkoutModel()
    @Published var watchDayProgramSequence: Int = 0
    @Published var exerciseVM: [WatchExerciseViewModel] = []
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case dayProgramSeq
        case exerciseVM
        
    }
    
    init() {
           //initiliazed empty view model via this function
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        watchDayProgramSequence = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)
        exerciseVM = try container.decode([WatchExerciseViewModel].self, forKey: .exerciseVM)
        
        do {
            watchDayProgramSequence = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            do {
                watchDayProgramSequence = try Int(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)) ?? 0
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encode(watchDayProgramSequence, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)
        try container.encode(exerciseVM, forKey: .exerciseVM)

    }//encode function ends
    
}
```

WatchApp

```
import SwiftUI
import Communicator

@main
struct WatchApp: App {

    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView(selectedTab: 0, receivedDayProgramVM: ReceivedDayProgViewModel())
            }
        }

        WKNotificationScene(controller: NotificationController.self, category: "myCategory")
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
import WatchKit
import Combine
import Communicator

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    
    @StateObject var receivedDayProgramVM = ReceivedDayProgViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            //Show WatchLoadingView, if dayprogramVM is being fetched
            if receivedDayProgramVM.exerciseVM.count == 0 {
                
                   WatchLoadingView()
                    .onAppear {
                        //Add Communicator functions if required
                         Blob.observe { Blob in

                             if Blob.identifier == "dayProgramData" {

                                 let ReceivedDayProgVMData = Blob.content
                                 print("WatchConnectivity blob setData printing \(ReceivedDayProgVMData)")

                                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                 
                                 let ReceivedDayProgViewModel = try! decoder.decode(ReceivedDayProgViewModel.self, from: ReceivedDayProgVMData)
                                 
                                 //Assign decoded class(parent view model) to environment object in contentView
//This is the line that causes error showing receivedDayProgramVM is get-only property
                                 receivedDayProgramVM = ReceivedDayProgViewModel

                                 
                             } //Blob for "dayProgramData" code ends
                             
                             
                         } //Blob observation code ends
                    } else {
                
                TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                    
                    WatchControlView().id(0)
                    SetInformationView().id(1)
                    SetRestDetailView().id(2)
                    //Check if WatchControlView can be vertically scrollable
                    NowPlayingView().id(3)
                }
                .environmentObject(receivedDayProgramVM)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

WatchLoadingView

```
import SwiftUI
import Communicator

struct WatchLoadingView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            let rect = geometry.frame(in: .global)
         
            VStack {
                ProgressView()
                Text("Fetching Data...")
                    .font(.body)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to separate your design into a view model and a model. `ReceivedDayProgViewModel` is clearly a model class and not a view model so you need a new type that you use as a StateObject in your view and that holds a reference to your model.

Comment: You can not recreate a StateObject. You can modify its properties with (mutating) func.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks so much for the guidance :) but I am still wondering if there could have been "shorter" or "more efficient" way of doing it than my codes below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my answer after getting the right clue from Joakim & Ptit's comments. **As per their advice, I have separated (data) model and view model for the watch app**.

It was a little time-consuming, but I managed to update the app design, and it enabled me to store transferred data into appropriate view model class.

See below code extract for future reference.

*WatchDayProgram Struct (Data Model)*

```
import Foundation
import Combine

struct WatchDayProgram: Codable {
    
    var watchDayProgramSequence: Int = 0
    var exerciseVM: [WatchExercise]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case dayProgramSeq
        case exerciseVM
        
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        watchDayProgramSequence = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)
        exerciseVM = try container.decode([WatchExercise].self, forKey: .exerciseVM)
        
        do {
            watchDayProgramSequence = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            do {
                watchDayProgramSequence = try Int(container.decode(String.self, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)) ?? 0
            }
        }

    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        try container.encode(watchDayProgramSequence, forKey: .dayProgramSeq)
        try container.encode(exerciseVM, forKey: .exerciseVM)

    }//encode function ends
    
}
```

*WatchDayProgViewModel*

```
import Foundation
import Combine

class ReceivedDayProgViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var workoutModel = WorkoutModel()
    @Published var watchDayProgramSequence: Int = 0
    @Published var exerciseVM: [WatchExerciseViewModel] = []
    
    
    init() {
           //initiliazed empty view model via this function, so empty view model class can be loaded onto Watch app when it starts while awaiting for the file transfer to be complete
    }
    
}
```

*ContentView*

```
import SwiftUI
import WatchKit
import Combine
import Communicator

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    
    @StateObject var receivedDayProgramVM = ReceivedDayProgViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            //Show WatchLoadingView, if dayprogramVM is being fetched
            if receivedDayProgramVM.exerciseVM.isEmpty == true {
                
                   WatchLoadingView()
                    .onAppear {

                         Blob.observe { Blob in

                             if Blob.identifier == "dayProgramData" {

                                 let ReceivedDayProgVMData = Blob.content
                                 print("WatchConnectivity blob setData printing \(ReceivedDayProgVMData)")

                                 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                 let ReceivedDayProgViewModel = try! decoder.decode(WatchDayProgram.self, from: ReceivedDayProgVMData)
                                 
                                 
                                 for (i, exercise) in ReceivedDayProgViewModel.exerciseVM.enumerated() {
                                     
                                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                         receivedDayProgramVM.exerciseVM.append(WatchExerciseViewModel(exercise: exercise))
                                     }

                                 
                             } //Blob for "dayProgramData" code ends
                             
                             
                         } //Blob observation code ends
                    } else {
                
                TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                    
                    WatchControlView().id(0)
                    SetInformationView().id(1)
                    SetRestDetailView().id(2)
                    //Check if WatchControlView can be vertically scrollable
                    NowPlayingView().id(3)
                }
                .environmentObject(receivedDayProgramVM)
            }

        }
    }
}
```